# Помогите, пожалуйста, связать 3 таблицы в sql

Tags: sql

| BEVERAGE | Store | Sells |
| --- | --- | --- |
| code | storename | storename |
| name | area | code |
| size | phone | price |

Помогите, пожалуйста, объединить 3 таблицы. В первой таблице `Beverage.code` равен `Sells.code`, `Store.storename` равен `Sells.storename`.
К сожалению, я только начал изучать sql, и этот язык дается очень тяжело.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM beverage INNER JOIN sells ON beverage.code = sells.code
                       INNER JOIN store ON sells.storename = store.storename
```